# Half-sphere vs disk energy absorption

Tags: energy, geometric-optics, geometry, absorption

If you placed a disk and a half-sphere made of the same, partially reflective material at the same distance from the (point) light source (distance measured to centre of sphere and middle of a disk), which object would absorb more energy per given time?

Answer (score 1):

Let's skip the detailed maths and find a short intuitive solution for this.I assume that both are of the same radius. We shall assume two cases:

CASE 1:(distance of source is finite)

The diagram for the sphere looks like this:
[image]

All the light emitted from $P$ will miss the sphere except the amount inside the cone $PAB$. Note that the flux through the spherical cap $AB$(the minor section of the sphere), is equal to that through a disc having diameter $AB$ placed along chord $AB$ (obvious) which is in turn equal to a disc of diameter $A'B'$ placed along line segment $A'B'$. But the disc diameter is clearly less than $A'B'$ which implies that the radiant flux is less as well. So the sphere absorbs more than the disc in this case.

CASE 2:(distance of source from the center is infinite)

The diagram looks like this:
[image]

You can clearly see here that the effective area is the same for both the objects now(i.e: both are $\pi r^2$). Thus the radiant flux will also be same in this case for both the hemisphere and the disc.

Comment: I wonder if it does depend on the distance thought (and light intensity) - could there be  a case where lower area would be compensated by parts of sphere being closer to the light source (and receiving more intense radiation due to inverse-square law) . Also I believe there is a case where sphere wins - when distance is small enough that light lies inside the hemisphere...

Comment: No, because there would be other areas of the sphere which are farther away. You must consider the flux of the radiation. That does not necessarily depend on the surface exactly